# How to check if object exists in mLab using _id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mlab

I am working on an angular application with a node.js backend where my architecture goes like this:

front-end => angular.service => node backend => mLab DB

Currently, I'm trying to push an object into the DB provided that it does not exist yet. If it already does, it should update. This function would be accessible via a button from the cards in my front-end.

to give a clearer understanding here's some of my code.

front-end: **admin-edit-home.component.html**

```
<a mdbBtn class='btn btn-md btn-primary' mdbWavesEffect (click)="addCard()">Add</a>
```

the code above is a button where I can add a card to the interface. The TS below shows how the code works.

front-end: **admin-edit-home.component.ts**

```
addCard() {
  this.carousels.push(this.carousels.length);
}
```

To give an explanation of the TS code, 'carousels' is an array that I use to do an *ngFor loop in my HTML wherein it presents the data in a card format. It is declared as:

```
carousels: any = [];
```

So in pushing a length to the 'carousels' array, it present an empty card with no collected data but still possessing the HTML elements from the original card which contains the supposed update function that I would like to have.

My problem is, how do I do the checking of the object existence from the back-end and present the results back to the front-end? I have tried this,

back-end: **api.js**

```
router.route('/carousel/update/:id').put(function(req,res) {
   var data = req.body;
   const myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };

db.collection('home').updateOne(myquery, {
   $set: {
       "header" : data.header,
       "subheader" : data.subheader,
       "img" : data.img
   }

  })
  if (myquery === -1) {
  arr.push(obj);
  } else {
      arr[myquery] = obj
  }
}
```

I know my back-end code is wrong and non-functional but I just wanted to let you guys have a visualisation of what my logic is trying to achieve.

Furthermore, this back-end code should now be accessible by my angular service through this chunk of code below:

**home.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable ({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HomeService {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   updateCard(id: string, header: string, subheader: string, img: string) {
       var json = {id: id, header: header, subheader: subheader, img: img}
       return this.http.put<any[]>(`./api/carousel/update/${id}`, json);  
   }
}
```

After trying these things, to sum up my problem in a more concise manner, I need to check from the database if the object is already existing via ObjectId and then update it through my input fields but if not, the updateCard() should create another object in my database. I hope to get help!

**EDIT**

```
 router.route('/carousel/update/:id').put(function (req, res) {
     var data = req.body;
     const myquery = { "_id": ObjectId };
    // console.log('header: ' + data.header + " id: " + data.id)
    console.log(req.params)
     db.collection("home").updateMany(myquery, {
         $set: {
             "img" : data.img,
             "header" : data.header,
             "subheader": data.subheader
         }
     }, (err, results) => {
        res.status(200).json({status: "ok"})
     })

 })
```

This is the new **api.js**. Please refer.

Comment: you can use upsert with update, upsert (if object is there update otherwise insert a new doc)

Comment: do you have an example for upsert usage? It's my first time hearing about it

Comment: db.collection.update( { query },{ update },{ upsert: true }) .  [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/]

Comment: the link that you have provided can't be found. I'll try something else.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: @Isaac Agatep My guess is that your put request format, try for this `return this._http.put('http://localhost:'port'/carousel/update/${id}`', YOUR_PARAMETER_HERE);` What is ./api in your code (updateCard method)??

Comment: Check my edit, that is my ./api method in the backend. In order for the button's card to reach the backend, I've used an angular service as stated above to communicate with the backend. So, api.js = backend, service.ts = controller, component.html = UI

Comment: What I am trying to do is, edit an object based on _id through a loop. If object exists in the loop, update it but if not, insert a new object.

Comment: @Isaac Agatep Totally confusing. ./api is a method in backend?? From frontend to connect to backend (through API) yous mould run backend in some port and call that API from frontend

Comment: the functions in api.js can be reached from the frontend using a generated service. The service is my middleware. Do you need a github repo?