# how to update an object from mLab collection using _id

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I currently have an api in my backend that can update my array. The problem is, it doesn't even reference the _id and only updates the first item in my array. Whenever I edit the values for the other objects and then click on update, it only updates the first object in my collection.

This is the code:

```
router.route('carousel/update/:id').put(function(req, res) {
var data = req.body;
const myquery = {"_id": ObjectId };

db.collection("home").updateOne(myquery, {
    $set: {
        "img": data.img,
        "header": data.header,
        "subheader": data.subheader
    }
}, (err, results) => {
   res.status(200).json({status: "ok"})}
})
```

This chunk of code allows me to update the first only the first object in my collection. How do i configure it otherwise in order to allow updating specific objects using the _id? What am I missing?

**EDIT**

After looking at other stack overflow posts, this is what I did:

```
const myquery = {"_id" : ObjectId(req.params.id) };
```

But now I get an error saying 'argument passed in must be a single string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters. Also when I console log, the ':id' part of the URL is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `updateOne` its should be `updateMany` as follows

```
db.collection("home").updateMany(myquery, {
```

`updateOne` will update the first document.

**EDIT**

Also look this line

```
const myquery = {"_id": ObjectId }; is incomplete
```

Should be

```
const myquery = {"_id": ObjectId("some id") };
```

Comment: Let me try this first.

Comment: updateMany now updates the same value for all my objects in the array instead of a specific object, which is not what I'm looking for. All objects now have the same value after updating.

Comment: @Isaac Agatep Actually what's ur requirement?? You want to update on a button click for that particular document??

Comment: Yes that’s what I would like to do. On my UI, each of my objects inside the collection are presented as values in input fields. Each object also has an update button where I can change the values for that particular object using the same input fields.

Comment: @Isaac Agatep Then your problem is with the query part.See my edited answer

Comment: It seems to me like I’ll need to hardcode a specific object’s _id into the query is that right? I haven’t tried it out yet, but I’ll do it as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi @Subburaj, I've edited my question since now my problem is that my id is undefined. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Isaac Agatep can you do `console.log(req.params)` and see what its printing??

Comment: it says undefined! I don't know why. Sorry I'm not so good at programming.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315104/how-to-check-if-object-exists-in-mlab-using-id This is my question that shows my code in-depth. Please take a look because maybe my approach is wrong. If need be, I can send you an invite for LiveShare.