# Mongodb upsert option with updateOne() does not work

Tags: node.js, angular, mlab

I'm currently tackling a problem whereas my code allows updates on object data through an *ngFor, but does not allow upsert through the updateOne() function.

Based on other posts, adding the modifier $set should solve the problem, which I have already incorporated with my code but to no avail.

This is my code.

***api.js (backend)***

```
router.route('carousel/update/:_id').put(function(req, res) {

  db.collection('home').updateOne({"_id": ObjectId(req.params._id)}, 
  {$set: req.body}, {upsert: true}, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results)

    console.log(results)
    console.log(req.params._id)
  });
});
```

In order to understand how my code works better, this is the angular service connecting my ***api.js*** to my component.ts.

***service.ts***

```
updateSlide(id: number, newheader: string, subheader: string){
   return this.http.put<any[]>('./api/carousel/update/' + id, {'header': newheader, 'subheader': newsubheader})
}
```

lastly, my component.ts file.

***component.ts***

```
carousels: any = [];

updateSlide(id: number){
  this.HomeService.updateSlide(id, this.header, this.subheader).subscribe(slides => {
this.carousels = slides;
console.log(slides)

})
}
```

With the above code, I expect the upsert option to create a new document when I try to update an object without an _id. Please bear with me as I'm a novice with MEAN!

***EDIT***

`console.log(req.body)` gives me a result of `{header: 'header', subheader 'subheader'}` which is similar to the data in my database.

`console.log(results)` return:

```
  result:
   { n: 1,
     nModified: 1,
     opTime: { ts: [Timestamp], t: 1 },
     electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001,
     ok: 1,
     operationTime:
      Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1571727952 },
     '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: [Timestamp], signature: [Object] } },
  connection:
   Connection {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        error: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        parseError: [Function],
        message: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 5,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     id: 0,
     options:
      { host: 'ds259367.mlab.com',
        port: 59367,
        size: 5,
        minSize: 0,
        connectionTimeout: 30000,
        socketTimeout: 360000,
        keepAlive: true,
        keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
        noDelay: true,
        ssl: false,
        checkServerIdentity: true,
        ca: null,
        crl: null,
        cert: null,
        key: null,
        passphrase: null,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false,
        reconnect: true,
        reconnectInterval: 1000,
        reconnectTries: 30,
        domainsEnabled: false,
        legacyCompatMode: true,
        disconnectHandler: [Store],
        cursorFactory: [Function: Cursor],
        emitError: true,
        monitorCommands: false,
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        clientInfo: [Object],
        servers: [Array],
        caseTranslate: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        auth: [Object],
        authSource: 'tawebdb',
        dbName: 'tawebdb',
        socketTimeoutMS: 360000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
        retryWrites: true,
        useRecoveryToken: true,
        readPreference: [ReadPreference],
        credentials: [MongoCredentials],
        bson: BSON {} },
     logger: Logger { className: 'Connection' },
     bson: BSON {},
     tag: undefined,
     maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
     port: 59367,
     host: 'ds259367.mlab.com',
     socketTimeout: 360000,
     keepAlive: true,
     keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
     connectionTimeout: 30000,
     responseOptions:
      { promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false },
     flushing: false,
     queue: [],
     writeStream: null,
     destroyed: false,
     hashedName: '09c68a091568e21c31a31a2ad4f8286db4fb6fb3',
     workItems: [],
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'ds259367.mlab.com',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        timeout: 360000,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 7,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]:
         Timeout {
           _called: false,
           _idleTimeout: 360000,
           _idlePrev: [TimersList],
           _idleNext: [TimersList],
           _idleStart: 14489,
           _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
           _timerArgs: undefined,
           _repeat: null,
           _destroyed: false,
           [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 1899,
           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 7 },
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     buffer: null,
     sizeOfMessage: 0,
     bytesRead: 0,
     stubBuffer: null,
     ismaster:
      { hosts: [Array],
        setName: 'rs-ds259367',
        setVersion: 1,
        ismaster: true,
        secondary: false,
        primary: 'ds259367-a.mlab.com:59367',
        me: 'ds259367-a.mlab.com:59367',
        electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001,
        lastWrite: [Object],
        maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
        maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
        localTime: 2019-10-22T07:05:40.313Z,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 6,
        readOnly: false,
        ok: 1,
        operationTime: [Timestamp],
        '$clusterTime': [Object] },
     lastIsMasterMS: 227 },
  message:
   BinMsg {
     parsed: true,
     raw:
      <Buffer f5 00 00 00 00 2c e8 09 04 00 00 00 dd 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 01 00 00 00 03 6f 70 ... >,
     data:
      <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 01 00 00 00 03 6f 70 54 69 6d 65 00 1c 00 00 00 11 74 73 00 01 00 00 ... >,
     bson: BSON {},
     opts:
      { promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false },
     length: 245,
     requestId: 166210560,
     responseTo: 4,
     opCode: 2013,
     fromCompressed: undefined,
     responseFlags: 0,
     checksumPresent: false,
     moreToCome: false,
     exhaustAllowed: false,
     promoteLongs: true,
     promoteValues: true,
     promoteBuffers: false,
     documents: [ [Object] ],
     index: 229,
     hashedName: '09c68a091568e21c31a31a2ad4f8286db4fb6fb3' },
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1 }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Would you like me to console.log it?

Comment: Give me a moment to provide an edited answer thanks!

Comment: Hi @Subburaj I've added the results from the console.log. Hope it helps.

Comment: when I log req.params._id, I get the value of an object's _id I have called using my update function. So the value depends on which object I update. Updating any object logs its _id.

Comment: @Subburaj any ideas?

Comment: @Subburaj I'll edit my question again and post the results.

Comment: @Subburaj I've updated the question and have shown the results from the console.log(results). Hope that helps!

Comment: @Subburaj Yes, I'm expecting it to insert a new document if the query doesn't match the filters I've provided. As for my function, my filter is the ObjectId and what I would like to achieve is to insert a new doc using the updateOne() if the query doesn't have an _id. But if object exists, update it.

Comment: @Subburaj if I don't pass the _id, then I won't be able to update anything. But according to mongodb, ```{upsert: true}``` checks whether or not an object exists and update, if not, insert a new object.

Comment: @Subburaj I am passing _id, what I want it to do is create a new object if it has no existing _id, and update only if _id exists.

Comment: @Isaac Agatep Thats what I am saying in my previous comments also, how do you verify its not working?? From the `results` what you have posted clearly says that its updating means data is there in your DB for the given query with `_id`

Comment: @Subburaj whenever I try to create a new object without _id, I get an error saying 'argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a strin of 24 hex characters'. This would mean that the object I'm trying to update doesn't have an _id so I expect it to insert using the option ```{upsert: true}```

Comment: @Isaac Agatep Your problem is totally different you should have posted the above error as your question then. Your problem is `ObjectId(req.params._id)` ObjectId will expect id string to be converted to ObjectId so its throwing error as you mentioned

Comment: @Subburaj in that case, how would I modify the code in order to correctly do an ```upsert```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for conditions as follows:

```
router.route('carousel/update/:_id').put(function(req, res) {
var id;
if(req.params._id == 'undefined')
  {
     id = '';. --------> have to careful there should not be any document with id='' in yourDB at any case
  } else {
    id = ObjectId(req.params._id)
  }

  db.collection('home').updateOne({"_id": id}, 
  {$set: req.body}, {upsert: true}, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results)

    console.log(results)
    console.log(req.params._id)
  });
});
```

Comment: @ Isaac Agatep Can you post your `req.params._id`??? May be it is different when u r not passing an _id

Comment: ```console.log(req.params._id)``` returns ```{_id: 5d9d84...........}``` if the object has an _id. However, it will throw error if no _id found.

Comment: @Isaac Agatep You need that exact error ..whether its `undefined` . you have to replace that with in if condition, so I need the exact value if _id is not found

Comment: if _id is not found, it just returns ```undefined```.

Comment: @Isaac Agatep i have updated my answer.Try for the above

Comment: I have tried your code, but it still throws me the same error. Maybe the error is not because of the api.js but rather the service.ts?

Comment: @Isaac Agatep Try for all combinations as `req.params._id == undefined` , `req.params._id == 'undefined'` my guess is its going to else condition so you have to give exact message of error in if condition

Comment: please help me review the code above and change modify the if statement into a ```if(req.params._id == 'undefined')``` instead. This finally works! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Isaac Agatep Finally your problem solved?? Accept this answer

Comment: please do the edit and I shall accept the answer :)

Comment: approved. Thanks!

Comment: @Isaac Agatep https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320668/how-to-update-an-object-from-mlab-collection-using-id/58320739#58320739 question posted you is also still open. I think its related to this question.Accept the answer so that question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

import ,

import org.mongodb.scala.model.UpdateOptions
and try like this::

```
updateOne(equal("vendor_id", vendorId),
      inc("views_count", views),
      UpdateOptions().upsert(true))
```